# Найти последнее вхождение регулярным выражением VBA

Tags: регулярные-выражения, excel, vba

Суть в том, что до недавнего времени массивы статусов отслеживания выдавало в обратной последовательности и мне нужен был первый, который есть, а теперь нужен последний. Собственно нужно переделать регулярное выражение, чтобы оно искало последнее вхождение.

Регулярное выражение:

```
"""lastPoint"":.*?""id"":"".*?"",""eventDateTime"":""(.*?)"",""operationDateTime"":""(.*?)"",""operationAttribute"":""(.*?)"",""operationType"":""(.*?)"",""operationPlacePostalCode"":""(.*?)"",""operationPlaceName"":""(.*?)"""
```

Массив данных:

```
{"status":"ok","data":{"trackCreationDateTime":"21.01.2020 16:57:36","trackUpdateDateTime":"31.01.2020 17:52:21","trackUpdateDiffMinutes":88,"trackDeliveredDateTime":"31.01.2020 12:49:50","fromCountryCode":"HK","fromCountry":"Honk Kong","fromName":"","destinationName":"Мис*** **********","destinationCountryCode":"","destinationCountry":"Russian Federation","destinationPostalCode":"241010","fromCity":"","destinationCity":"","fromAddress":"","destinationAddress":"","collectOnDeliveryPrice":"","declaredValue":"","deliveredStatus":"1","trackCodeModified":"","awaiting":true,"events":[{"id":"2608897999","eventDateTime":"23.01.2020 09:44:56","operationDateTime":"23.01.2020 11:31:00","operationAttribute":"Прием","operationType":"","operationPlacePostalCode":"","operationPlaceName":"Гонконг AMC","itemWeight":"0","source":"rupost","serviceName":"Почта России","operationAttributeInformation":"Означает, что зарубежный отправитель (продавец) принес Вашу посылку в местное почтовое отделение. При этом заполнил все необходимые документы, включая таможенную декларацию (формы CN 22 или CN 23). В это время отправлению присваивается уникальный почтовый идентификатор – специальный штриховой код (Трек-номер, Трек-код). Он находится в чеке (или квитанции), выдаваемом при приеме почтового отправления. Операция «Прием» показывает место, дату и страну приема отправления. После приема посылка движется на пути к месту международного обмена.","operationAttributeOriginal":"Прием","operationTypeOriginal":"","operationPlaceNameOriginal":"Гонконг AMC"},{"id":"2622234099","eventDateTime":"31.01.2020 17:52:21","operationDateTime":"31.01.2020 12:49:50","operationAttribute":"Прибыло в место вручения","operationType":"","operationPlacePostalCode":"241010","operationPlaceName":"Брянск 10","itemWeight":"86","source":"rupost","serviceName":"Почта России","operationAttributeInformation":"Означает прибытие отправления в отделение почтовой связи (ОПС) получателя, которое должно произвести вручение отправления получателю.  Как только отправление прибыло в отделение, сотрудники выписывают извещение (уведомление) о том, что отправление находится в отделении. Извещение отдают почтальону в доставку. Доставка осуществляется в день прибытия отправления в отделение или на следующий день (например, если отправления поступили в отделение вечером).&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;\nДанный статус указывает на то, что получатель может самостоятельно обратиться в почтовое отделение связи для получения отправления не дожидаясь извещения.\n&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;\nЕсли посылка была переупакованна в пакет с другими посылками, то для возможности получения Вам необходимо узнать трек-код общей посылки.","operationAttributeOriginal":"Прибыло в место вручения","operationTypeOriginal":"","operationPlaceNameOriginal":"Брянск 10"}],"itemWeight":"86","trackFirstOperationDateTime":"23.01.2020 11:31:00","daysInTransit":9,"daysTracking":11,"groupedCompanyNames":["Почта России"],"groupedEvents":"","lastPoint":"","destinationPostalAddress":"Брянская обл. г. Брянск Федюнинского проезд дом 18","destinationPostalPhones":"(4832) 55-04-46","destinationPostalWorkTime":"пн-пт :08:00-20:00  перерыв 13:00-14:00 сб :09:00-18:00  перерыв 13:00-14:00 вс :выходной"},"services":["UPU","HKPOST","CLVLNKS","EXP4PX","CAINIAO","DHLGR","JNET","FLYT","EMPSEXP"],"deliveredStat":{"minDeliveryDays":"10","averageDeliveryDays":"15","maxDeliveryDays":"19","type":"Регистрируемое почтовое отправление"},"id":"497c5fbe4be542a39f9bf69047dfae36","rpm":1,"totalTime":0.0874}
```

Более удобный вид для чтения

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "data": {
        "trackCreationDateTime": "21.01.2020 16:57:36",
        "trackUpdateDateTime": "31.01.2020 22:21:11",
        "trackUpdateDiffMinutes": 0,
        "trackDeliveredDateTime": "31.01.2020 12:49:50",
        "fromCountryCode": "HK",
        "fromCountry": "Honk Kong",
        "fromName": "",
        "destinationName": "Мис*** **********",
        "destinationCountryCode": "",
        "destinationCountry": "Russian Federation",
        "destinationPostalCode": "241010",
        "fromCity": "",
        "destinationCity": "",
        "fromAddress": "",
        "destinationAddress": "",
        "collectOnDeliveryPrice": "",
        "declaredValue": "",
        "deliveredStatus": "1",
        "trackCodeModified": "",
        "awaiting": true,
        "events": [
            {
                "id": "2608897999",
                "eventDateTime": "23.01.2020 09:44:56",
                "operationDateTime": "23.01.2020 11:31:00",
                "operationAttribute": "Прием",
                "operationType": "",
                "operationPlacePostalCode": "",
                "operationPlaceName": "Гонконг AMC",
                "itemWeight": "0",
                "source": "rupost",
                "serviceName": "Почта России",
                "operationAttributeInformation": "Означает, что зарубежный отправитель (продавец) принес Вашу посылку в местное почтовое отделение. При этом заполнил все необходимые документы, включая таможенную декларацию (формы CN 22 или CN 23). В это время отправлению присваивается уникальный почтовый идентификатор – специальный штриховой код (Трек-номер, Трек-код). Он находится в чеке (или квитанции), выдаваемом при приеме почтового отправления. Операция «Прием» показывает место, дату и страну приема отправления. После приема посылка движется на пути к месту международного обмена.",
                "operationAttributeOriginal": "Прием",
                "operationTypeOriginal": "",
                "operationPlaceNameOriginal": "Гонконг AMC"
            },
            {
                "id": "2622234099",
                "eventDateTime": "31.01.2020 17:52:21",
                "operationDateTime": "31.01.2020 12:49:50",
                "operationAttribute": "Прибыло в место вручения",
                "operationType": "",
                "operationPlacePostalCode": "241010",
                "operationPlaceName": "Брянск 10",
                "itemWeight": "86",
                "source": "rupost",
                "serviceName": "Почта России",
                "operationAttributeInformation": "Означает прибытие отправления в отделение почтовой связи (ОПС) получателя, которое должно произвести вручение отправления получателю.  Как только отправление прибыло в отделение, сотрудники выписывают извещение (уведомление) о том, что отправление находится в отделении. Извещение отдают почтальону в доставку. Доставка осуществляется в день прибытия отправления в отделение или на следующий день (например, если отправления поступили в отделение вечером).&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;\nДанный статус указывает на то, что получатель может самостоятельно обратиться в почтовое отделение связи для получения отправления не дожидаясь извещения.\n&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;\nЕсли посылка была переупакованна в пакет с другими посылками, то для возможности получения Вам необходимо узнать трек-код общей посылки.",
                "operationAttributeOriginal": "Прибыло в место вручения",
                "operationTypeOriginal": "",
                "operationPlaceNameOriginal": "Брянск 10"
            }
        ],
        "itemWeight": "86",
        "trackFirstOperationDateTime": "23.01.2020 11:31:00",
        "daysInTransit": 9,
        "daysTracking": 11,
        "groupedCompanyNames": [
            "Почта России"
        ],
        "groupedEvents": "",
        "lastPoint": "",
        "destinationPostalAddress": "Брянская обл. г. Брянск Федюнинского проезд дом 18",
        "destinationPostalPhones": "(4832) 55-04-46",
        "destinationPostalWorkTime": "пн-пт :08:00-20:00  перерыв 13:00-14:00 сб :09:00-18:00  перерыв 13:00-14:00 вс :выходной"
    },
    "services": [
        "RUPOST",
        "UPU",
        "HKPOST",
        "CLVLNKS",
        "EXP4PX",
        "CAINIAO",
        "DHLGR",
        "JNET",
        "FLYT",
        "EMPSEXP"
    ],
    "deliveredStat": {
        "minDeliveryDays": "10",
        "averageDeliveryDays": "15",
        "maxDeliveryDays": "19",
        "type": "Регистрируемое почтовое отправление"
    },
    "id": "352ecde1f8ca2d639a1c05963e48e779",
    "rpm": 0,
    "totalTime": 0.1191
}
```

Собственно получается есть массив events и из этого массива нужно брать из последнего элемента массива такие атрибуты как
operationDateTime, operationAttribute, operationType, operationPlacePostalCode, operationPlaceName.

Comment: Добавьте в самом начале `.*` (или `[^]*`)

Comment: Лучше в конец добавить группу про отсутствие какого-нибудь из обязательных атрибутов.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, Спасибо большое. Получается требовалось удалить всего один символ, а именно ?

Comment: Согласен с ответившим Вам @Andrey: не стоит городить огород регулярок, если на входе - стандартный формат, такой как JSON, и есть модуль для его преобразования в нормальный объект

Answer (score 2):

Полностью рабочий пример без регулярок по json'у (имхо - зло)

> До начала использования необходимо:
>   1. Скачать и импортировать в проект модуль парсера [от Tim Hall](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) (в примере использован он)
>   2. Для работы парсера необходимы словари. В References подключаем модуль "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" (если вдруг не подключен)
>   3. Вместо блока `With json_str` Может быть использаован любой удобный для Вас способ получения json в переменную типа `String`. Соответственно, из этого блока Вам понадобится только строка  `Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(var_your_string)` где `var_your_string` Ваша переменная содержащая JSON

```
Sub example()
    Dim json_str As New ADODB.Stream, json As Object, data_dict As Dictionary, i&, events_qty&

    With json_str
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Mode = adModeReadWrite
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile "C:\temp\template.json"
        .Position = 0
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.ReadText)
        .Close
    End With

    If Not IsEmpty(json("data")("events")) Then events_qty = json("data")("events").Count

    For i = 1 To events_qty

        Set data_dict = json("data")("events").item(i)

        Debug.Print data_dict("operationDateTime")
        Debug.Print data_dict("operationAttribute")
        Debug.Print data_dict("operationType")
        Debug.Print data_dict("operationPlacePostalCode")
        Debug.Print data_dict("operationPlaceName")
    Next
End Sub
```

В данном случае `json("data")("events")` является коллекцией т.е. `Collection` (Если такие данные в json присутсвуют, в противном случае `Empty`) которая содержит словари. Каждый элемент коллекции имеет свойства объекта `Dictionary`. Поэтому в случае необходимости получения последнего значения можно вместо цикла записать так:

```
If events_qty > 0 Then 
    Set data_dict = json("data")("events").item(events_qty)
    Debug.Print data_dict("operationDateTime")
    Debug.Print data_dict("operationAttribute")
    Debug.Print data_dict("operationType")
    Debug.Print data_dict("operationPlacePostalCode")
    Debug.Print data_dict("operationPlaceName")
End If
```

Или если мы хотим обратиться к объекту коллекции по его номеру:

```
If required_record_num <= events_qty Then 
    Set data_dict = json("data")("events").item(required_record_num)
    Debug.Print data_dict("operationDateTime")
    Debug.Print data_dict("operationAttribute")
    Debug.Print data_dict("operationType")
    Debug.Print data_dict("operationPlacePostalCode")
    Debug.Print data_dict("operationPlaceName")
End If
```

В случае если Вам необходимо обратиться к событию с определенным `id`:

```
For i = 1 To events_qty
    if json("data")("events").item(i)("id") = your_required_id Then
        Set data_dict = json("data")("events").item(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Debug.Print data_dict("operationDateTime")
Debug.Print data_dict("operationAttribute")
Debug.Print data_dict("operationType")
Debug.Print data_dict("operationPlacePostalCode")
Debug.Print data_dict("operationPlaceName")
```